# What SSD technology has cheapest data recovery service?

Tags: ssd

SSDs might fail rarely, but when they fail they do so grandly. Data recovery services typically charge thousands of euros even for the smallest drives.

Of course the cheapest data recovery technology is **backing up in advance**, and there are many services out there, but I'm not interested in "what ifs".

Sometimes a formerly working SSD isn't recognised at all by the motherboard, or seems not to be powered any longer, or has some other failure which prevents any interaction with it. In such cases, it's sometimes enough to replace a chip/controller inside, or something even simpler (which of course shouldn't be done at home).

Does any SSD technology, producer or line stand out as having a feature which probably or provably makes data recovery cheaper? Or vice versa one which is clearly the worst of class, neighbourhing [planned obsolescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planned_obsolescence)? (The former would be for instance a drive which is absolutely impossible to open without destroying it.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about manufacturing processes for a wide variety of manufacturers. It may lead to a product recommendation in the future, but as written, it is too broad. If you can focus your question to a small selection of manufacturers, it may be more on topic.

Comment: @Andy I don't think it's too broad. Answering it might as easy as finding one data recovery company which says "we can repair SSD X, but not SSD Y, Z".

Comment: It is cheaper, simpler, and more reliable to plan for avoiding the data recovery scenario ever becoming relevant in the first place. I guess most customers of data recovery companies are the kind of people who didn't plan on how to prevent data loss. If you do run a RAID-1 across two SSD and are unlucky enough to have both die on you within a too short time frame to replace the defective SSD, you will still be better off in a data recovery scenario, because you have two physical media you can send off for data recovery rather than just one.

Comment: @kasperd I acknowledged that in the question itself, but when I choose an SSD I don't necessarily control all the other data loss factors and I can still want to consider them all albeit with different weights.

Comment: Cheapest data recovery is backups ;)

Comment: Disappointing. This is definitely on topic and there are entire studies from consumerist associations and scientific labs on durability design of products. I'll answer myself at some point.